# Find the row of highest numbers from each of names or group who'd has been have a some of similarity of names then sumif their values group of names

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, formula, spreadsheet, array-formulas

I want to make the total of values every each member or names in every each their own group at the first match (or after blank space) or highest values positions of each them on column "**D**" according to column "**B**" with the result's row of an output like the exactly as an **EXPECT OUTPUT** as act of what I've just created on column "**E**". That's the **replace a little bit down of just only one row from the column** "**B**" **positions** or row must be the same as the column "C" and "D". Could we do this anyway ?

**My achievements:** I feel I've tried this before and got succeed to achieve this but I've forgot how to solve this when that happened. But it's look like kinda this code of formula:

```
=FILTER(IF(IFERROR(MATCH($B$3:$B;$B:$B;0);0)=ROW($B$3:$B);SUMIF($B$3:$B;$B$3:$B;$D$3:$D);"");$B$3:$B<>"0")
```

I don't know if I'm right or wrong but please see the table I'd created at the down below this and  also see how I expected with that and feel free as well to edit to my doc file of google sheet I attached down below this.

[THIS HERE YOU CAN EDIT TO MY SAMPLE G.SHEET TO SOLVE THIS MY QUIZ. THANKS IN ADVANCE!](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1JKVcsRuLAirCwUeIpRylzEiAkSOLNgroHbizF58m7Ys/edit?usp=share_link)

|  | A | B | C | D | E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 |  |  |  |  |  |
| 2 | **N U M B** | **I D - M E M B E R** | **I D - C O D E** | **V A L U E S** | **E X P E C T O U T P U T** |
| 3 |  |  |  |  |  |
| 4 | 4 | JYFI7 |  |  |  |
| 5 |  | JYFI7 | J3573 | 3 | 6 |
| 6 |  | JYFI7 | IYR | 1 |  |
| 7 |  | JYFI7 | F498S | 2 |  |
| 8 |  |  |  |  |  |
| 9 | 3 | DFJ9F11 |  |  |  |
| 10 |  | DFJ9F11 | C684J | 7 | 8 |
| 11 |  | DFJ9F11 | J58 | 1 |  |
| 12 |  |  |  |  |  |
| 13 | 2 | H684K |  |  |  |
| 14 |  | H684K | JF585 | 2 | 2 |
| 15 |  |  |  |  |  |
| 16 | 1 | FJSR |  |  |  |
| 17 |  | FJSR | 4684 | 7 | 16 |
| 18 |  | FJSR | 834 | 1 |  |
| 19 |  | FJSR | 49 | 2 |  |
| 20 |  | FJSR | 9835 | 6 |  |

Comment: Please any input or suggest is needed to make this question better becauses I needed.  ^_^

Comment: Thanks @marc_s was edited my wrong of words to my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a possible solution:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(LAMBDA(cusum,IF(SCAN(,cusum,
LAMBDA(acc,cur,if(cur="",,acc+1)))=1,cusum,))
(SORT(SCAN(,SORT(D3:D,ROW(D3:D),0),
LAMBDA(acc,cur,if(cur="",,acc+cur))),ROW(D3:D),0)))
```

You can find it in tab 'z' cell F3.

Comment: wow ...   it's wonderful @ztiaa!  So in that case is that's a code of your formula doesn't need the criteria like on column "B" right ?

Comment: yes. The formula is designed to align with the first number of each group in the D column.